# New at Twitter API V2

Tags: api, twitter, bearer-token

I wanted to start learning about Twitter API V2 so, I created a developer account and created my first app. I saved the  api key, api key secret and my Bearer token.
But when I tried the example in the documentation in my terminal it didn't work.

what I am doing wrong ?
[error I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFocS.png)

Comment: Please do not post screenshots. I realise that you may have done this to hide your secret value, which is good practice, but you should post in text instead (and replace your secret with something else)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `<` and `>` characters from the bearer token string value. They are there to denote that the whole value should be replaced with your bearer token.